# Загрузка в расширении хром

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Как в расширении хром скачивать файлы, и если возможно самому формировать файл который скачает пользователь?

Answer (score 0):

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt","This is the content of my file :)");
```

`text/plain` - подставляете свой тип файла который нужен

[Источник](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)